# the accuracy formula of classification using lda

Tags: classification, linear, accuracy, discriminant-analysis

what is the formula of accuracy linear discriminant system as classifier?
is the multi class and 2 class have same formula of accuracy?

i tried to find it in google but cant find one, help me please

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the **loss function**, then there are several options, which don't depend on the method used (e.g. LDA), but rather on the objective (in your case classification/prediction). [This](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13748-014-0060-7) article compares three loss functions and concludes the Hamming loss works best for multilabel classification.

The **Hamming loss**, as described [here](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/HammingLoss) is defined as:

$$\frac{1}{|D|} \sum_{1}^{|D|} \frac{xor (y_i, \hat{y})}{|L|}$$

Where $y_i$ is the actual label, $\hat{y}$ the predicted label, $|D|$ the number of samples and $|L|$ the number of labels.

This is not the same as binary classification, where the loss function is  typically the **0/1 loss**:

$$I(y_i \neq \hat{y})$$